# Check null condition in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

In my `PROCEDURE` if `IN_CLIENT_ID is null` then its return the row where `GLOBAL_ID` is null and if `IN_CLIENT_ID` have some value then its return the row that `GLOBAL_ID=IN_CLIENT_ID`.
When i use `GLOBAL_ID=IN_CLIENT_ID` result is ok if IN_CLIENT_ID have some value.But not for if `IN_CLIENT_ID` is null.

Then i check `IN_CLIENT_ID is null` out side of query and its working. But i don't want to write same query two times.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE123(
  IN_CLIENT_ID IN VARCHAR2,
  EXP_RECORDSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN 
    IF IN_CLIENT_ID IS NULL THEN
        OPEN EXP_RECORDSET FOR  
        SELECT client.id  FROM GLOBAL_CLIENT client 
              WHERE  AND client.GLOBAL_ID IS NULL
          ORDER BY client.id;
    ELSE
        OPEN EXP_RECORDSET FOR  
        SELECT client.id  FROM GLOBAL_CLIENT client 
              WHERE  AND client.GLOBAL_ID=IN_CLIENT_ID
          ORDER BY client.id;
    END IF;
END;
```

Is there any way apply if condition in WHERE clause.

Comment: To clarify, you want to return the `client.id` where both values are NULL or both values exist and are equal?

Comment: @toonice yes ..

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCEDURE123(
    IN_CLIENT_ID IN VARCHAR2,
    EXP_RECORDSET OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
) AS
BEGIN 
    OPEN EXP_RECORDSET FOR  
    SELECT client.id
    FROM GLOBAL_CLIENT client
    WHERE DECODE( client.GLOBAL_ID,
                  client.IN_CLIENT_ID,
                  1,
                  0 ) = 1
    ORDER BY client.id;
END;
```

The above is as per https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f%3Fp%3D100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4410543900346652511.

If you have any questions or comments, then please feel free to post a Comment accordingly.

Comment: First solution working In second result have redundancy. client.IN_CLIENT_ID --> give error invalids identified. I remove client. and its working.. Thanks

Comment: If i want ignore the IN_CLIENT_ID if its null. Like if IN_CLIENT_ID is null then its show all the records..

Comment: If i want ignore the IN_CLIENT_ID if its null. Like if IN_CLIENT_ID is null then its show all the records..

Comment: I was worried about that.  I shall remove the second option from my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by USING AND OR conjunctions in where clause

```
OPEN EXP_RECORDSET FOR  
    SELECT client.id  
    FROM GLOBAL_CLIENT client 
    WHERE  ( IN_CLIENT_ID IS NULL AND client.GLOBAL_ID IS NULL) OR 
           ( IN_CLIENT_ID IS NOT NULL AND client.GLOBAL_ID=IN_CLIENT_ID)
    ORDER BY client.id;
```